# How do I set the layout for the python console & variable explorer

Tags: pycharm

I prefer to have the python console on the side, and for this layout it would look a lot better if the variable inspector that is associated with this console would appear above/below the console, in stead of side-by-side (as is the default, which I cannot seem to change).
I have tried different combinations of docked, pinned and windowed mode, but non of them allow me to change the relative position between the variable inspector and the console.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like this,

[image]

you can drag out either variable inspector or console and put it back under the remaining tab in the tool-window.